# UEFI BIOS does not list nvme

Tags: boot, uefi, ssd, bios, nvme

I currently run Ubuntu 22.04 on a small ssd (sdc). I would now like to move to larger drive. Therefore I connected a nvme to the M2 port of the motherboard (Gigabyte ga-h97-d3h_f7) and installed 22.04. Problem: the BIOS doesn’t list the nvme and I cannot boot from it.

Additional information:

- Board supports M2
- SATA Port enabled in BIOS
- SATA Mode Selection set to AHCI
- BIOS upstated to latest version
- nvme listed in gparted, Disks and Nautilus

The only reference to nvme I could find in the logs says: "nvme nvme0: allocated 32 MiB host memory buffer."

I let boot repair analyse the pc and then ran it as recommended. It should have installed grub on the nvme, but after a restart the system booted into sdc again (old ssd). Again the nvme wasn’t listed in the BIOS. [Pastebin](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Zjbz72xfC4/)

I’d appreciate any hints as to how I proceed from here.

Regards,
Florian

```
treebeard@florian-home:~$ lsblk -o NAME,UUID,LABEL,FSTYPE
NAME        UUID                                LABEL FSTYPE
sda                                                  
└─sda1      3CECE8015D533D10                        ntfs
sdb                                                  
└─sdb1      7298AD2F71D18046                        ntfs
sdc                                                  
├─sdc1      8229-FB8C                               vfat
├─sdc2      c259c206-e88e-443e-8af6-7d08e8c096b0    ext4
└─sdc3      d9c471f5-8756-4d49-a5cf-a94687b25fcb    ext4
sr0                                                  
nvme0n1                                              
├─nvme0n1p1 C2F7-0B6D                               vfat
├─nvme0n1p2 8aa012a8-b3b6-4dcc-8c44-956b9138cf78    ext4
└─nvme0n1p3 b6288eb0-b7be-452e-9360-dd6e069dc190    ext4

treebeard@florian-home:~$ sudo parted -l
[sudo] password for treebeard: 
Model: ATA WDC WD10EARX-00N (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  1000GB  1000GB  primary  ntfs

Model: ATA WDC WD20EZRX-00D (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 2000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  2000GB  2000GB  primary  ntfs

Model: ATA SanDisk SD8SBBU1 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdc: 120GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name                  Flags
 1      1049kB  512MB   511MB   fat32        EFI System Partition  boot, esp
 2      512MB   30,5GB  30,0GB  ext4
 3      30,5GB  120GB   89,5GB  ext4

Model: WD Blue SN570 500GB (nvme)
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 500GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name  Flags
 1      1049kB  512MB   511MB   fat32              boot, esp
 2      512MB   60,5GB  60,0GB  ext4
 3      60,5GB  481GB   420GB   ext4

treebeard@florian-home:~$ sudo lshw -C system
florian-home             
    description: Desktop Computer
    product: H97-D3H (To be filled by O.E.M.)
    vendor: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd.
    version: To be filled by O.E.M.
    serial: To be filled by O.E.M.
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: smbios-2.7 dmi-2.7 smp vsyscall32
    configuration: administrator_password=disabled boot=normal chassis=desktop family=To be filled by O.E.M. frontpanel_password=disabled keyboard_password=disabled power-on_password=disabled sku=To be filled by O.E.M. uuid=03d40274-0435-05ab-de06-f40700080009

treebeard@florian-home:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 06)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller (rev 06)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 9 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Controller
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 9 Series Chipset Family ME Interface #1
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection I217-V
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 9 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI Controller #2
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 9 Series Chipset Family HD Audio Controller
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 9 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev d0)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 9 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev d0)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 9 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI Controller #1
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation H97 Chipset LPC Controller
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 9 Series Chipset Family SATA Controller [AHCI Mode]
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 9 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller
01:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Sandisk Corp WD Blue SN570 NVMe SSD
02:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev 41)

treebeard@florian-home:~$ sudo efibootmgr -v
BootCurrent: 0003
Timeout: 1 seconds
BootOrder: 0003,0000,0001,0002
Boot0000* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,50656e35-6c79-44e4-b8d7-c21975bee797,0x800,0xf3800)/File(\EFI\UBUNTU\SHIMX64.EFI)
Boot0001* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,50656e35-6c79-44e4-b8d7-c21975bee797,0x800,0xf3800)/File(\EFI\UBUNTU\GRUBX64.EFI)
Boot0002* UEFI OS    HD(1,GPT,50656e35-6c79-44e4-b8d7-c21975bee797,0x800,0xf3800)/File(\EFI\BOOT\BOOTX64.EFI)
Boot0003* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,50656e35-6c79-44e4-b8d7-c21975bee797,0x800,0xf3800)/File(\EFI\PRECISE-SERVER\SHIMX64.EFI)
```

Comment: Can you elaborate "installed 22.04 via gparted"? And also if BIOS doesn't see a drive, it is not an OS issue.

Comment: Sorry, I meant I installed via usb stick. There are three partition nvme0n1p1 ist /boot/efi, p2 is /, p3 is /home. Re BIOS, all the other drives are listed in the SATA Config, the nvme doesn't. Also, it is doesn't appear in the boot options.

Comment: Your UEFI boot entry uses the GUID/partUUID of sdc1. Make sure you do not have conflict with M.2 & SATA ports. Systems disable a SATA port when M.2 is used. You can use Boot-Repair to reinstall grub using advanced mode where you choose install and choose drive. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair & 
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/ Report shows both UUID entry & drive. You can also see with `lsblk -e 7 -o name,fstype,size,fsused,label,partlabel,mountpoint,uuid,partuuid`
& 
`sudo efibootmgr -v ` check fstab. You may need to first update fstab's UUID for ESP.

Comment: Thanks @oldfred. The UUID in the fstab was correct, so I ran the boot repair as you recommended. Unfortunately it didn't work. I got:"An error occurred during the repair.
Error: NVram is locked ( not found in efibootmgr). Please report this message to boot.repair@gmail.com

Please write on a paper the following URL:
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/rwSWxZbDjN/

Locked-NVram detected." I will check this later today, just wanted to update my question in the forum.

Comment: Seeing more of NVram locked issue. It relates to some setting in UEFI, not just the Secure Boot setting. This user posted a variety of settings he changed. HP Zbook 15 NVRAM locked, install issues
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2482555