# Unable to get M.2 with 22.04 to work

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi

I installed Ubuntu 22.04 on new M.2. I then tried to change to bootloader from my current ssd (sdc, also on 22.04) to the M.2 (nvme) using boot repair. When changing hard drives in the past I used boot repair in order to be able to boot from the new drive. This time, however, it didn't work. https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/CykqYbGmsG/

Boot Info After Repair:
=> No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/nvme0n1.
=> libparted MBR boot code is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda.
=> libparted MBR boot code is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdb.
=> No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdc.

Additional information:

- Motherboard is Gigabyte ga-h97-d3h_f7 (from around 2014)
- Board supports M2
- SATA Port enabled in BIOS
- SATA Mode Selection set to AHCI
- BIOS updated to latest version
- nvme listed in gparted, Disks and Nautilus - not in BIOS

In my post from Jan 23, [UEFI BIOS does not list nvme](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1449139/uefi-bios-does-not-list-nvme), I had basically described the same problem. When I ran boot repair last week I got different results, although I'm not aware I have changed anything since. That confuses my, so I post again and would appreciate any advice re this issue. Many thanks.

Florian

````
[sudo] password for treebeard: 
Model: ATA WDC WD10EARX-00N (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  1000GB  1000GB  primary  ntfs

Model: ATA WDC WD20EZRX-00D (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 2000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  2000GB  2000GB  primary  ntfs

Model: ATA SanDisk SD8SBBU1 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdc: 120GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name                  Flags
 1      1049kB  512MB   511MB   fat32        EFI System Partition  boot, esp
 2      512MB   30,5GB  30,0GB  ext4
 3      30,5GB  120GB   89,5GB  ext4

Model: WD Blue SN570 500GB (nvme)
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 500GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name  Flags
 1      1049kB  512MB   511MB   fat32              boot, esp
 2      512MB   60,5GB  60,0GB  ext4
 3      60,5GB  481GB   420GB   ext4

treebeard@florian-home:~$ sudo lshw -C system
florian-home                
    description: Desktop Computer
    product: H97-D3H (To be filled by O.E.M.)
    vendor: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd.
    version: To be filled by O.E.M.
    serial: To be filled by O.E.M.
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: smbios-2.7 dmi-2.7 smp vsyscall32
    configuration: administrator_password=disabled boot=normal chassis=desktop family=To be filled by O.E.M. frontpanel_password=disabled keyboard_password=disabled power-on_password=disabled sku=To be filled by O.E.M. uuid=03d40274-0435-05ab-de06-f40700080009
  *-pnp00:00
       product: PnP device PNP0c01
       physical id: 0
       capabilities: pnp
       configuration: driver=system
  *-pnp00:01
       product: PnP device PNP0c02
       physical id: 1
       capabilities: pnp
       configuration: driver=system
  *-pnp00:02
       product: PnP device PNP0b00
       physical id: 2
       capabilities: pnp
       configuration: driver=rtc_cmos
  *-pnp00:04
       product: PnP device PNP0c02
       physical id: 4
       capabilities: pnp
       configuration: driver=system
  *-pnp00:06
       product: PnP device PNP0c02
       physical id: 6
       capabilities: pnp
       configuration: driver=system
  *-pnp00:07
       product: PnP device PNP0c02
       physical id: 7
       capabilities: pnp
       configuration: driver=system
       
treebeard@florian-home:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 06)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller (rev 06)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 9 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Controller
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 9 Series Chipset Family ME Interface #1
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection I217-V
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 9 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI Controller #2
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 9 Series Chipset Family HD Audio Controller
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 9 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev d0)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 9 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev d0)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 9 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI Controller #1
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation H97 Chipset LPC Controller
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 9 Series Chipset Family SATA Controller [AHCI Mode]
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 9 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller
01:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Sandisk Corp WD Blue SN570 NVMe SSD
02:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev 41)

treebeard@florian-home:~$ sudo efibootmgr -v
BootCurrent: 0000
Timeout: 1 seconds
BootOrder: 0000,0002,0003
Boot0000* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,50656e35-6c79-44e4-b8d7-c21975bee797,0x800,0xf3800)/File(\EFI\UBUNTU\SHIMX64.EFI)
Boot0002* UEFI OS   HD(1,GPT,50656e35-6c79-44e4-b8d7-c21975bee797,0x800,0xf3800)/File(\EFI\BOOT\BOOTX64.EFI)
Boot0003* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,50656e35-6c79-44e4-b8d7-c21975bee797,0x800,0xf3800)/File(\EFI\UBUNTU\GRUBX64.EFI)

treebeard@florian-home:~$ lsblk -e 7 -o name,fstype,size,fsused,label,partlabel,mountpoint,uuid,partuuid
NAME FSTYPE   SIZE FSUSED LABEL PARTLABEL MOUNTPOINT UUID                                 PARTUUID
sda         931,5G                                                                        
└─sda1
     ntfs   931,5G 569,8G                 /mnt/3CECE 3CECE8015D533D10                     a9e9f62d-01
sdb           1,8T                                                                        
└─sdb1
     ntfs     1,8T 376,6G                 /mnt/7298A 7298AD2F71D18046                     a30a6203-01
sdc         111,8G                                                                        
├─sdc1
│    vfat     487M  19,1M       EFI System Partition
│                                         /boot/efi  8229-FB8C                            50656e35-6c79-44e4-b8d7-c21975bee797
├─sdc2
│    ext4    27,9G  24,1G                 /          c259c206-e88e-443e-8af6-7d08e8c096b0 af619954-0481-4df4-a01c-2db26f316ec0
└─sdc3
     ext4    83,4G  52,9G                 /home      d9c471f5-8756-4d49-a5cf-a94687b25fcb f73184cf-8307-43ab-a936-98d724e9af72
sdd          57,7G                                                                        
└─sdd1
     vfat    57,7G  27,7G                 /media/tre 70E7-58A1                            178ed896-01
sr0          1024M                                                                        
nvme0n1
│           465,8G                                                                        
├─nvme0n1p1
│    vfat     487M   486M                 /mnt/C2F7- C2F7-0B6D                            42040cbe-d6d9-4ee3-8fa3-8d28ddad5797
├─nvme0n1p2
│    ext4    55,9G   8,1G                 /media/tre 8aa012a8-b3b6-4dcc-8c44-956b9138cf78 38e1ab2d-dbf3-4420-a491-eb3c3ce37522
└─nvme0n1p3
     ext4   391,2G    44K                 /media/tre b6288eb0-b7be-452e-9360-dd6e069dc190 1795cd97-f01f-401a-af06-1c46ccf7faf8```


  [1]: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1449139/uefi-bios-does-not-list-nvme
````

Comment: Better to post link to Summary Report from Boot-Repair. But not good that UEFI does not see drive, and surprised then Ubuntu does. Does motherboard support NVMe or only M.2 SATA? I think 2014 was about the time NVMe just started. My 2016 build, I used SATA as NVMe was very expensive then. Check manual, often M.2 consumes a SATA port, so you may have conflict?

Comment: Did you boot Boot Repair in UEFI mode? those MBR errors make me think you didn't.

Comment: Thanks @oldfred . You were right, the manual doesn't mention nvme. I didn't know that there is a difference as the specs I checked only list M.2. It's listed under "protocol", however. I guess, the protocol I need is AHCP.

Comment: @OrganicMarble My BIOS is set to boot in UEFI and I didn't change that. So, I suppose that's not the issue - but thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I meant AHCI.

Comment: I think we, including me, confuse M.2 which is a connector and SATA port which is a connector with SATA, NVMe as drivers used with whatever physical connection is used. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M.2